# scroll to anchor in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have some larger content on my own server, and a parent (main) page from where they can be chosen and read. The whole seemed not very complicated so I thought that I can use a simple html with some javascript. The content is displayed in an iframe with id "TextFrame".

Now, If I have a toc with references like

```
<a href="Book2.htm#Chapter7" target="TextFrame">Chapter 7 in the Second Book</a>
```

I get the document Book2.htm into the iframe, and it is scrolled to the id #Chapter7 - as long as I try it with a simple link from a test parent html file to the file called Book2.htm.

Now, I actually load the file - optionally in two languages - from my server, so I add two parameters calling a javascript function:

```
function LoadContent(theref) {
  var ifrm = document.getElementById('TextFrame');
  var Language1 = document.getElementById('Language1');
  var Language2 = document.getElementById('Language2');

  ifrm.src = theref+'?Lang1='+Language1.value+'&Lang2='+Language2.value;
}
```

This works, too.

But now, I want the text in the iframe to scroll to Chapter 7 (to the target reference).
Constructions like

```
ifrm.src = 'Book2#Chapter7?Lang1=FRA&Lang2=ENG'
```

are not even transferred to the server...
Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, URL fragments (the  part after `#`) are not sent to the server. That's why you should follow this construction order:

```
scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

More info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax).

Hence, to build your URL:

```
ifrm.src = 'Book2.html?Lang1=FRA&Lang2=ENG#Chapter7'
```